# How to save all embedded images of local html file in Windows

Tags: html, windows, image

I know that there are kinds of variations on this topic here but I have not found a single solution that works...

I want to automate the extraction process and save all images into a folder.

**My question**

How to save **all embedded images** of a **local html file** in **Windows**?

Comment: Can you please provide more info? like, if you are able to open that html file in browser, you can then right-click on each image and save them. If you want to do that by code, then you should find HTML parser to extract <img> tags from the html file and use any online converter to convert it to PNG/JPG

Comment: @MuhammadOmarElShourbagy: I edited the answer: I want to automate the process because there are many images in the file (yes, I can open it in a browser).

Comment: Assuming your encoding is `data:image/png;base64`, you'd extract the "text" from each embedded image and save separately as `.txt` files. Then run `certutil -decode img.txt img.png`.

Comment: @chrisaycock: Thank you, would you mind to form an answer out of this with some more details (e.g. how to extract the "text" of the images in one go)?

Comment: @vonjd I can't make a proper answer at the moment, but I'll give a quick note. To extract the text, ideally you'd use an XML parser on the file to pull `img` tags. In a pinch, you might get away with regex, though that should be your last option.